# categories appear in one post laravel

Tags: laravel

why all categories appear in one post, I just want to display the value category that matches the post.

[image]

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
   $categories = Category::all();
   $tags = Tag::all();
   return view('admin.post.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}

<select id="category" name="categories[]" style="width: 100%" multiple>
@foreach($categories as $category)
<option
@foreach ($categories as $postCategory)
{{ $postCategory->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
@endforeach
value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#category").select2({
placeholder: "Please Select"
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: no where in this code are you using `$post` so you couldn't possibly be checking what categories it has

Comment: how is a Post related to a Category? a `category_id` field on `posts` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$post` will have a `category_id` you just need to check that field against the `id` of the current `$category` being iterated:

```
<select id="category" name="categories[]" style="width: 100%" multiple>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option {{ $post->category_id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
        value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```